# How to put text under the title of table (caption)?

Tags: latex

I need to add a  reference under the title of my table and this was my code. However, the reference appear in the Table content. I need just to add reference under the title of the table before the tabular without adding it to the table content.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
    \tabcolsep=0.3cm
\centering
\caption{Dataset statistics \cite{reference_here}} 
%\vspace{-.2cm}
\label{table:dataset}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Statistic}                               & \textbf{Count} \\ \midrule
\# of A                  & 800    \\
\# of B                &   36,681   \\
\# of C                &   36,681   \\
\# of D                &  112,480 \\
Total E & 723,360 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\vspace{-.3cm}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define two different caption texts, one for the actual table and one for the list of tables:

```
\caption[version for LoT]{Dataset statistics \cite{reference_here}}
```